# Azure AD User auto provision in Salesforce

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, salesforce

I have one Salesforce profile and one permission set in Salesforce. As per the requirement, there are two user personas in our Salesforce application.

Persona 1 -> SF Profile
Persona 2 -> SF Profile + Permission Set

To achieve the above configuration using Azure AD auto-provision, we have created two security groups and added relevant business users into those two groups. Currently, we struggling to determine the best approach on how to assign the Salesforce permission sets to the users in the "Persona 2" user group.

Comment: What have you tried for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have Single Sign-On configured in SF, right? At the bottom of the page there's place for just-in-time (JIT) login handler class.

[image]

You'd have to write that class but there are some online examples for [`... implements Auth.SamlJitHandler`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_Auth_SamlJitHandler.htm). Once you have the class skeleton ready - use `System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(attributes));` or something similar to see what Azure Active Directory sends. Last time I used this AAD couldn't send groups info but it could send role(s). So we determined unique sets of users and if role is X - check if the user has permission set X assigned and if not - assign it. We then expanded it to other SF features (groups, queues, user role, profile...). `PermissionSetAssignment` is the table you need.

If you don't want to write code for this there's always [Identity Connect](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/identity_connect) but that's paid and on-premise agent program (I think). No idea if it can work with AAD. But you'll get simple interface for the mapping.

Comment: Thanks mate. This is definitely one possible solution and seems flexible to expand further. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: Check https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_saml.htm&type=5. They write that SF will generate a sample class for you which you'll have to massively cut down. For example you don't care about community SSO so Account and Contact-related code goes away. I don't remember whether I used generated one or the one in documentation. Well, you can't do it straight in prod anyway, you'll have to tweak in sandbox and deploy. Good luck. Also, the "AAD couldn't send groups" - I'm no AAD admin, I don't remember if it's real limitation or quirk because client configured something that way....

Answer (score 0):

In order to get aad groups you have to make a second call to get the users groups.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).